# Jackson Serialization/Deserialization Polymorphism many-to-one using existing property

Tags: jackson, polymorphism, jackson-databind

I have a class XDevice which subclasses the Device class.
I have JsonTypeName annotations of both of these classes which i use for serialization/deserialization using an existing property 'type' in Device class.

Below are the annotations on the class.

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
        property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = XDevice.class, name = "XDev"),
})
@JsonTypeName("Dev")
public class Device
```

The child class XDevice just contains one annotation *@JsonTypeName("XDev")*.
The type field is an enumeration which supports many other type values for future needs.
Now there is a new type value possible "Dev1" which needs to be serialized/deserialized to the Device object also.
I am not sure how i can do this , since this type value is not a subclass and i already have a single JsonTypeName annotation on the Device class.
Any help would be appreciated.